# Actual Text Width android

Tags: android, width, textview, measure

I require actual Text width from a TextView.

To expalin this heres my TextView description:

1. TextView lies in a LinearLayout with some internal padding.
2. TextView is set to fill the width and wrap up the height.
3. TextView has a leftCompoundDrawable set and a rightCompoundDrawable set.
4. Theres also padding given to text of textview from left compound drawable.
5. Text from text view can be multiline.

What I meant from *text* from *TextView* is property of TextView which can be set using `android:text` property from XML or by calling setText() on TextView.

Heres what I am doing.

```
[ScreenWidth]-[LeftCompundDrawableIntrinsic Width]-[RightDrawabaleIntrinsicWidth]-[LeftCompoundDrawablePadding]
```

**is there any stock method from framework which can precisely caluclate this ?**

Heres an image describing my TextView

[image: TextView]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TextView tv;
Rect rc=new Rect();
//...
for(int i=0; i < tv.getLineCount(); i++)
{
   tv.getLineBounds(line, rc);
   Log.v(TAG, "Line #"+i+", left="+rc.left+", right="+rc.right);
}
```